# OffsetHeight Calculation

Tags: javascript, html

WHen i use offsetHeight in a function, for all the browser the offsetHeight result is different for different Browser.

Is there any way in which the result is same for all.?

For firefox am getting 40 and for IE 38. Can it be same for all the browsers

```
 <body>
  <div id="container">
     <div id="richText">
        Resi9 is het volledige gamma modulaire apparatuur integreerbaar in modulaire kasten voor woningen en andere residentiële toepassingen.<br>
        Het omvat de volgende productfamilies :

    </div>

  </div>

<script>

var height=document.getElementById("richText").offsetHeight;

alert("height" + height);



</script>
 </body>
```

Comment: I guess you get different results because the height is really different.

Comment: But the content is same in all browsers

Comment: Yes, but browsers have different rendering engines, you have to get used to such discrepancies in web development.

Comment: padding,line-height,font-family,font-size, font-style, font-weight all affect the display size of an element, and may be different or be calculated differently on different browsers.

Comment: I want to build a application in which same size content should be visible rest should be overflow hidden in all browser. SO how can i calculate the same exact height so i can trim accordingly

Comment: Can you use jQuery?  OuterHeight(true) will be the same in every browser.

Comment: @Gary Even outerHeight(true) is different for different browsers

Comment: Usually the biggest culprit, even if you get all styles consistent, is that fonts may render at different sizes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using @font-face? Some browsers may not support @font-face or woff2 fonts, in which case it will use a local font file instead and therefore cause the offsetHeight to differ.