# Strange chrome behavior on javascript function to resize a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I've wrote a script to resize a div, relative to the size of another div's height plus 70px (Which is the size of the margin (top and bottom)) and loaded it in window.onload function.

```
        <script language="JavaScript">
        function tamanho_wrapper2(){
            var mydiv = document.getElementById("topicos");
            var current_height = parseInt(mydiv.offsetHeight);
            var wrapper2 = document.getElementById("wrapper2");
            wrapper2.style.height = current_height+70+"px";

        }
    </script>
```

It is working on firefox, the div is exactly how I wanted it to be. 
But on chrome, in the first page's loading, it includes the bottom and top margin's size in the height of the div which I am getting the height, so the div gets bigger than I desired. The wierd is that when the page is reloaded, chrome counts only the self height of the div, as firefox. Have it already happen to you?

**Edit:** Well, the conclusion I've got in the end, is that old fact: browsers' engine work different and what is happening to me is a prove. Thanks for your attention guys.

**Edit2:** Magically, the browser's strange behavior stopped to happen.

Comment: Very strange. You may want to try using JQuery and seeing if it works using a JQuery approach.

Comment: The comments here maybe explains the behavior http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138887/offsetheight-calculation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to reset your stylesheet (link above). All browsers have their own default styles for each element, maybe Chrome is adding it`s default style to your div, other browsers may show it int different ways too.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

PS: Sorry, my english is worse sometimes :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your javascript doesnt work in Chrome, it looks spot on to me. Have you tried using jquery? I just tested this i chrome and had no adverse effects. I hope it helps :)

```
<div id="div1" style="background-color:#ff0000; height:50px; width:10px; float:left;"></div>

<div id="div2" style="background-color:#00ff00; height:150px; width:10px; float:left;"></div>

<input type="button" value="resize" onclick="resizeDiv();" />
```

Then this jquery code:

```
function resizeDiv(){
$('#div1').css('height', $('#div2').css('height'));
}
```